# Modern.IE VM license

Tags: licensing, windows, virtual-machine

Microsoft provides some [VMs for testing purposes](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) (advertised on Stack Overflow) and I'm trying to understand [the license terms](https://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/virtualmachine_instructions_2014-01-21.pdf). The one I don't really understand is

> 1.b. You may use the software for testing purposes only. You may not  use the software for commercial purposes.

My thoughts:

1. Testing a website in several browsers on several different virtual machines seems a quite professional approach. I hardly believe many private developers would do that. Of course they should, but which private developer has the time to do so?
2. If that's really only available to private developers, what is the offer to companies doing the same thing? I am missing the advertisement for a paid service.

Is testing by a company considered a commercial purpose? Can I use the VMs within a company for testing or not?

Comment: Read here:
https://github.com/xdissent/ievms/issues/157 and here:
http://davidwalsh.name/free-ie-vms Make use of available licensing tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see where this would be confusing for a non-native speaker of English.

Microsoft sees three general environments:

- Development
- Test
- Production

You may use the virtual machines for the middle environment, but not the first or third.

The production environment is presumably the one used to generate revenue (make money) or is the one used for commercial purposes.

So they are happy for you to test like crazy and for free, but when you develop<sup>1</sup> or start trying to make money off of the product then they want to be paid for their product.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Develop in this case would be a bit difficult as the VMs don't contain any development tools.  You could install development tools on a VM, but you would be violating the terms of service.</sub>

Comment: Ok, that's great. Do you have a reference to those 3 general environments?

Comment: Have a look at the Environments section under the Wikipedia article on [Software Development Life Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle)

Answer (score 0):

We considered using these VMs at my workplace, and asked about using them.

Our internal Windows administrators checked and told us that "You may not use the software for commercial purposes." does indeed mean that you are not allowed to use it at all if you are a company, not even for testing purposes. I do not know where they obtained the information, but as they are responsible for our licensing, I see no reason not to trust them.

So the answer probably is:

- **No**, a company may not use the VMs provided by http://modern.ie/ .
- A company will have to obtain the appropriate number of Windows licenses, usually from their reseller. How to do this and how much it costs will depend on your contract with Microsoft.

Of course, as with all licensing questions, details depend on your jurisdictions. In some jurisdictions the restrictions in Microsoft's license may not be enforceable, so maybe you can still use them. For that you'd need some expert in copyright law.

Comment: So, what exactly would be the point of MS releasing these VMs if you weren't allowed to use them on your local machine to test how your website works in them?  I think your licensing guy doesn't know what he's talking about, as the same terms apply to MSDN downloads as well.  As long as the VMs' only use is testing your website, you're abiding the license.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, I wondered about that, too. I don't know why the license is the way it is - though I suppose MS have their reasons. As to MSDN downloads: I just looked at one of their licenses (MS Visual Studio Community edition ) and it does _not_ restrict to non-commercial use. Still, even IANAL and all that, I do not see how developing software for money can not be considered "commercial use", so I stand by my answer.

Comment: Community edition license is a bit different than MSDN licensing.  This might help.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx  The fact is though the VM license explicitly says you can use the VMs for testing.  I don't think you can just throw out that clause due to the commercial use clause.  Otherwise anyone could make a contract and then bury in it elsewhere "just kidding, all that stuff previously was a lie."  To balance your answer, a previous employer had someone look into these VMs and said it looked fine for us to use.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for the information. Consider posting this as an answer :-).